# AWS CLI output does not include property descriptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

`aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier aurora-postgresql-build-1`

produces the following output (excluded some unique identifier names/ARNs etc.):

```
DBINSTANCES     1       False   eu-west-1c      1       rds-ca-2019     False   False
aurora-postgresql-build <arn here> db.r5.large     aurora-postgresql-build-1 
available       0       <some thing that might be sensitive>   False   aurora-postgresql
11.9    False   2020-12-01T15:44:01.505000+00:00        <another arn here>
postgresql-license      postgres        0       False   False   01:18-01:48
wed:02:19-wed:02:49     0       False   True    aurora
```

It's ok for things like cluster identifier or engine type, but `False` explains nothiing and occurs multiple times. How can I make the query return list of column names or some sort of description of what returned values are describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure your CLI to return `text` instead of `json`?  Check the output setting in your `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=text
```

If you update your output to `json`, this should return something that has the property names along with the values in the output.  I believe json is the default but you can update the setting in this file to override it for all commands.

If you want to just override the output for a single command, you can also add `--output json` to the end of your command such as:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier aurora-postgresql-build-1 --output json
```

The format options are: `json`, `yaml`, `yaml-stream`, `text`, `table`

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html